# QT menu - on the left side

Tags: qt

I'm just trying out QT, and I want to make a "list" containing a menu on the left site of the window, just as it is in the QTCreator. (I made a screenshot of that "list")

I tried some things, editing the design, but i dont have any idea, how to make such a "list".

[image: showing the list i mean]

Comment: Try to use qtreewidget or qlistview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertical customized (using qt style sheets) QToolBar may look and feel pretty same as this one in Qt Creator

Comment: This in my opinion. You can choose whether you want icons, or texts, or both. You can even make it floatable/movable, if the user wishes to change it himself.